# SQL Server - mirror some columns from tables to another database on the same server without replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, replication

I have a SQL Server 2012 Web Edition (11.0.5058.0) instance on a VPS which hosts two databases. I would like to mirror a couple of columns from 3 tables to the second database, but I don't have transactional replication installed.

So I have a `Staff` table on the source database - I just want the `staff_code` and `unique_id` - I have an `Activity` table - I just need the `activity_code`, `description` and `unique_id`.. etc.

What is the best way to go about this - would that be triggers? The data is not regularly updated, possibly once a week - but I would still like the synchronisation to be fast if possible?

The data in the source database may be deleted, updated or inserted, by another application, so I want to ensure the data in my database reflects that information correctly.

Thanks for any suggestions!

UPDATED: Table comparison example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
     ( SELECT [COLUMN1],[COLUMN2],[UNIQUE_ID] FROM [SOURCE-DATABASE].[dbo].[SOURCE-TABLE]
       EXCEPT 
       SELECT [COLUMN1],[COLUMN2],[UNIQUE_ID] FROM [DESTINATION-DATABASE].[dbo].[DESTINATION-TABLE]
     ) 
         AND NOT EXISTS 
     ( SELECT [COLUMN1],[COLUMN2],[UNIQUE_ID] FROM [DESTINATION-DATABASE].[dbo].[DESTINATION-TABLE]
       EXCEPT 
       SELECT [COLUMN1],[COLUMN2],[UNIQUE_ID] FROM [SOURCE-DATABASE].[dbo].[SOURCE-TABLE]
     ) 
     THEN 'True' 
     ELSE 'False' //GRAB NEW OR UPDATED DATA
   END AS result ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the two databases can be connected (e.g. can you do a `SELECT * FROM SecondDB.dbo.Activity`?), then I would just

- set up a query (stand-alone, or in a stored procedure) that just checks whether or not the data on the source has changed
- updates the second database using normal `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and possibly `DELETE` statements
- set up that query/stored procedure with a SQL Server **Agent Job** to run at regular intervals, e.g. once every night, once every week - whatever works for you

I don't think triggers would be a good choice here - triggers should be kept very small, lean, fast - and "replicating" to another database sounds like too much processing work for a nimble trigger.... (also if you triggers take a long time to complete, the calling application will have to wait for that whole time..... not good for your application performance!)

Comment: OK that sounds like the best approach - now I have written a little compare query (posted in my original question above), what is the best practice for synchronising the destination table.. truncate and insert or do an update?